# How should I forward Intent parameters through chains of Activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I have lots of Activities chained together with Intents and some Intents require parameters passed in the extras Bundle. When I have to forward parameters through multiple Activities, should I copy each one explicitly or is there a best-practice way of doing it? For instance, I could clone-copy the current Intent as a starting point for calling other subtask Intents, and this would (presumably) copy all previous Bundle parameters.

As an illustration, say you have a file explorer Activity that is in one of two modes: Expert and Novice. You want to pass this state to some subtask Activity like a file properties page, which you could do by calling putExtra("skillLevel", "Expert") on the Intent before you launch it. Now if the property page also has a subtask Activity, compression options for instance, how should you forward on the "skillLevel" parameter?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think the best and cleaner way to do it is to initialize the next `Intent` using the received `Intent` through the [`Intent(Intent)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28android.content.Intent%29) constructor.

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(receivedIntent);
```

Comment: Thanks! I needed more than Extras so I use it in this way and then I set the component to indicate where to go: `otherIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(context, MyIntentService.class));`

Comment: It's even easier if you use the solution mentioned by @Gary

Answer (score 98):

I dont know why you would want to copy all the other properties using a constructor.

```
newIntent.putExtras(oldIntent);
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Intent is object here, not class. Right?

Comment: How do I get these back?

Comment: emphasis on the "s" at the end of `putExtras`.  Missed it for a bit.

Answer (score 2):

If a parameter is system wide, it may be easier to store it in Shared Preferences until it is changed (such as difficulty of a game). It would have the side effect of remembering the set difficulty when the user leaves the app.

Comment: This is a very good point and actually SharedPreferences would be better than Intents for managing the state of the "Skill Level" in the example I gave. However, my real problem (which isn't very example-friendly) can't use a single global state variable in this way.

Answer (score -2):

Since we don't have Global variables in Android you can create a class with your application wide informations and use the Singleton pattern . Since it will be changed for all the system, this way you can always get the same instance of this object, hence always the same information.

An example:

```
public class Object {

private static Object instance;

private Object objectcall;  

private Object(){

}

public void setObject(Object newObject){
    this.objectcall = newObject;

} 


public  Object getObject(){
    return this.objectcall;
}


public static synchronized Object getInstance(){

         if(instance==null){    
           instance=new Object();
         }
         return instance;

}
}
```

when you want to retrieve it in a Activity just call

```
Object objectSingleton = Object.getInstance();
```

Comment: Downvoted, because this method ignores the Android Activity lifecycle. Thus, this approach is prone to unpredictable behavior/crashes, for example when the system destroys and later recreates an Activity due to low memory.

Intent parameters, on the other hand, are stored by the system and will be passed to the Activity on recreation.